# Undefined namespace when using Unirest

Tags: php, api

I have installed unirest using composer by adding this code to composer.json

```
{
"require-dev": {
    "mashape/unirest-php": "3.*"
}
```

}

I have called the autoloder in the begining of my file

```
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

and I'm getting Undefined variable on Unirest

```
$response = Unirest\Request::post($endpoint, json_encode($oauthRequestHeaders));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either declare the classes you "use" at the top of your script:.

```
use Unirest\Request;
$response = Request::post($endpoint, json_encode($oauthRequestHeaders));
```

or, with a leading backslash with the fully qualified namespace.

```
$response = \Unirest\Request::post($endpoint, json_encode($oauthRequestHeaders));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem 
I cloned this project from github

https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php.git

Then called the Unirest file.

```
require_once '/path/to/unirest-php/src/Unirest.php';
```